# How to continue one thread at a time when debugging a multithreaded program in GDB?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb, pthreads

I have a program which uses two threads. I have put the break point in both the threads. While running the program under gdb I want to switch between the threads and make them run.
(thread t1 is active and running and thread t2; when paused on the breakpoint. I want to stop T1 running and run the T2).

Is there any way that I can schedule the threads in gdb?

Comment: See the GDB manual page on [Debugging Programs with Multiple Threads](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html#Threads), specifically you want to use the `thread` command to switch the active thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using GDB 7 or later, try "non-stop mode".

http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html

The "scheduler-locking on" command previously mentioned allows you step one thread with the others stopped.  Non-stop mode allows you to step one thread with the others active.

Comment: This seems converse to the question, but it's good to know this command exists anyway.

Answer (score 57):

By default, GDB stops all threads when any breakpoint is hit, and resumes *all* threads when you  issue any command (such as `continue`, `next`, `step`, `finish`, etc.) which requires that the inferior process (the one you are debugging) start to execute.

However, you can tell GDB not to do that:

```
(gdb) help set scheduler-locking 
Set mode for locking scheduler during execution.
off  == no locking (threads may preempt at any time)
on   == full locking (no thread except the current thread may run)
step == scheduler locked during every single-step operation.
    In this mode, no other thread may run during a step command.
    Other threads may run while stepping over a function call ('next').
```

So you'll want to set breakpoints, then `set scheduler-locking on`, then `continue` or `finish` in thread 1 (thread 2 is still stopped), then Ctrl-C to regain control of GDB, switch to thread 2, `continue` (thread 1 is still stopped), etc.

Beware: by setting `scheduler-locking on` it is very easy to cause the inferior process to self-deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

use break conditions

```
(gdb) break frik.c:13 thread 28 if bartab > lim
```

see [Debugging with GDB](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_toc.html#TOC43)

Edit:

```
(gdb) break <thread_function_entry_point> thread 2
(gdb) break <thread_function_entry_point> thread 1
(gdb) thread 1
(gdb) continue
(gdb) ... thread 1 finishes
(gdb) thread 2
(gdb) continue
```

You can put these commands inside a .gdbrc file.

Comment: My requirement is I want one thread to finish 1st then start running the 2nd one.

Comment: (gdb) break <thread_function_entry_point> thread 2
(gdb) break <thread_function_entry_point> thread 1
(gdb) thread 1
(gdb) continue
(gdb) ... thread 1 finishes
(gdb) thread 2
(gdb) continue

Comment: This will not work: 'continue' (by default) resumes *all* threads.